# Wordpress - Responsive navbar doesnt work

Tags: navigation

i have a website that uses wordpress. I created a navbar but it doesnt work properly.
In small screens. After clicking "open menu" The menu doesnt appear. 
[image]

My Codes:

PHP:

```
<div class="menu-bar"><div class="container margin-top-0 padding-0"><div class="menuAc">MENÜYÜ AÇ </div> <ul> <li> <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1' ) ); ?></li> </ul> </div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-bar{ background-color: #1a2a3c; border-top: 5px solid #9e1e1e; border-bottom: 5px solid #9e1e1e; color:#fff;  overflow: hidden;}
.menu-bar a{ padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style-type: none; text-decoration: none;}
.menu-bar ul li {float: left; margin-right: 40px; list-style-type: none;  }
.menu-bar ul li a{  z-index:9999;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:18px;
    letter-spacing:.7px;
    padding:15px 12px;
font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif !important;}
.menu-bar ul li a:after{
    z-index:-1;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:0%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: #9e1e1e;
    transition:height 150ms;}
.menu-bar ul li a:hover{ color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
.menu-bar ul li a:hover:after{height: 100%;}
.menuAc {
    background-color: #2e3b4c;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
    .menu-bar .menuAc{display:block;}
    .menu-bar ul {display:none;}
    .menu-bar ul li{float:none; margin-right:0; border-bottom:1px solid #333}
    .menu-bar ul li:last-child{border-bottom:none}
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .menu-bar ul {display:block!important;}
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var a = 0;
    $('.menuAc').click(function(){
        if ( a == 0 ){
            $(this).text('MENÜYÜ GİZLE');
            a++;
        } else {
            $(this).text('MENÜYÜ AÇ');
            a = 0;
        }
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are there any JS errors in your console?

Comment: no there is not any error